# Activiti bpmn2 file placeholder for tragetRef

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn, flowable

Is there any way to define targetRef/sourceRef/id of bpmn2 flows as variables.

eg. something like this

```
<sequenceFlow id ="flow1" sourceRef = ${placeholderVariable1}, targetRef = ${placeholderVariable2}>
```

So that , when the process excutes, it dynamicall have sequence flow based on the variable value (id of defined service task in xml file)being set in code.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a BPMn standard - why would this be needed? How could the model even be visualized?  Why not use message start events and/or gateways with conditionals?

Comment: Writting a custom error handling, since every step/task  has to have a flow to the exception service task, instead of defining sequence flow for each task , thought if something like could be done or not, its true that it will not be visualized, but since error handaling is at very micro level and technical in nature,  not an issue if its not visualized

Comment: Consider using an error boundary event, and a link to the service task that handles the error.